# Parsing binary data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-applications, 3d, binary-data, file-handling

I want to design and write a 3d image viewing web application in JavaScript. I've already written it in java and flash and basically want to port it. I want the 3d image export files to be in a binary format just like the Java and flash versions I've written however, I'm unsure if JavaScript can handle data in binary format efficiently. Can JavaScript handle binary data quickly? How good/bad is it at handling compared with Java and Flash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript can handle binary data via [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays). And here is a [library](https://github.com/jDataView/jDataView) for dealing with binary files, that you can use as a reference point for your application.

How quick is JavaScript - I'm not sure that this is the right question. It depends on browser, and user`s machine.

Answer (score 4):

As @Bakudan said, you can use the [`TypedArray`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays).

Most modern browsers support the [`DataView` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView), which provides you random access to [`ArrayBuffer`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer).

As addition, you can use [`BlobReader` to process blobs](https://github.com/mgechev/blobreader).

The whole process of parsing binary protocols (Blobs, ArrayBuffers, DataViews, TypedArrays, Binary Data over WebSockets) is described in [this blog post](http://blog.mgechev.com/2015/02/06/parsing-binary-protocol-data-javascript-typedarrays-blobs/).

Comment: It's worth noting the jDataView/jBinary polyfill/extension of the DataView standard.